# to detect patches in binary images using opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to detect all the patches in the [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfJjR.jpg)image, I attached the code used to detect them:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


image=cv2.imread("bw2.jpg",0)

# convert to RGB
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
# create a binary thresholded image
_, binary = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 500, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
# show it
plt.imshow(gray, cmap="gray")
plt.show()
# find the contours from the thresholded image
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(gray, cv2.RETR_TREE, 
cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
print("contours:",contours)
# draw all contours
for c in contours:
if cv2.contourArea(c) < 3000:
    continue

(x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
#cv2.rectangle(image, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

## BEGIN - draw rotated rectangle
rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
box = np.int0(box)
cv2.drawContours(image,[box],0,(255,51,255),2)

# show the image with the drawn contours
plt.imshow(image)
#plt.imshow(im3)

cv2.imwrite("detectImg2.png",image)
plt.show()
```

I get output image as here[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqMcn.png)

I want to detect all of them, can anyone tell me how to achieve this I new to image processing

Comment: You cannot crop the rotated rectangle. You can make the background outside the rotated rectangle transparent or you can crop to the normal bounding box of the rotated rectangle.  Please give more details what you are actually wanting or show an example output. Please take the **tour** (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), regarding, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I actually want to crop the patches and rotate it straightly, I hope u may understand

Comment: You need to crop to the bounds of the rotated rectangle making the background white, then rotate to straighten it, then crop again.. The cv2.minAreaRect() will return the rotation angle you need to use to rotate. Then use contours to find the bounds by making the background white when rotating and get the contour bounding box. Or get the rotated rectangle corners and rotate them accordingly and use the rotated corners to crop the image from the bounding box of the corners. Please read the tour in this forum and post your current code as far as you have it.

Comment: As you said I put all information here, I achieved half of them, but still missing some patches in the image.

Comment: I do not understand what you want.  Are you trying to get the rotated rectangle of the cluster of white or of each white region separately. I think the latter, but want to be sure I understand. Do I understand that you are not detecting all of them? Perhaps your area threshold is too small?

Comment: can you answer my another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62230063/to-find-and-rotate-a-image-from-vertical-to-horizontal-using-opencv-python?noredirect=1#comment110060749_62230063, I cannot find solution for this too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I would extract and rotate each blob in your image using Python OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Convert to gray
- Threshold
- Apply morphology open and close to clean small spots
- Get all the external contours
- Loop over each contour and do the following:
- Draw the contour on a copy of the input image
- Get the rotated rectangle of the contour and extract its center, dimensions and rotation angle
- Get the corners of the rotated rectangle
- Draw the rotated rectangle on another copy of the input
- Correct the rotation angle for image unrotation
- Generate a mask image with the filled rotated rectangle
- Apply the mask image to the morphology cleaned image to remove near-by other white regions
- Get the affine warp matrix using the center and corrected rotation angle
- Unrotated the the masked image using warpAffine
- Get the contour of the one blob in the unrotated image
- Get the contours bounding box
- Crop the masked image (or alternately crop the input image)
- Save the cropped image
- Exit the loop
- Save the contour and rotrect images

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread("bw2.jpg")
hh, ww = image.shape[:2]

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# create a binary thresholded image
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# apply morphology
kernel = np.ones((7,7), np.uint8)
clean = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
kernel = np.ones((13,13), np.uint8)
clean = cv2.morphologyEx(clean, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)


# get external contours
contours = cv2.findContours(clean, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]

contour_img = image.copy()
rotrect_img = image.copy()
i = 1
for c in contours:
    # draw contour on input
    cv2.drawContours(contour_img,[c],0,(0,0,255),2)

    # get rotated rectangle from contour
    # get its dimensions
    # get angle relative to horizontal from rotated rectangle
    rotrect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
    (center), (width,height), angle = rotrect
    box = cv2.boxPoints(rotrect)
    boxpts = np.int0(box)

    # draw rotated rectangle on copy of image
    cv2.drawContours(rotrect_img,[boxpts],0,(0,255,0),2)

    # from https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/20/text-skew-correction-opencv-python/
    # the `cv2.minAreaRect` function returns values in the
    # range [-90, 0); as the rectangle rotates clockwise the
    # returned angle tends to 0 -- in this special case we
    # need to add 90 degrees to the angle
    if angle < -45:
        angle = -(90 + angle)

    # otherwise, check width vs height
    else:
        if width > height:
            angle = -(90 + angle)

        else:
            angle = -angle

    # negate the angle for deskewing
    neg_angle = -angle

    # draw mask as filled rotated rectangle on black background the size of the input
    mask = np.zeros_like(clean)
    cv2.drawContours(mask,[boxpts],0,255,-1)

    # apply mask to cleaned image
    blob_img = cv2.bitwise_and(clean, mask)

    # Get rotation matrix
    #center = (width // 2, height // 2)
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, neg_angle, scale=1.0)
    #print('m: ',M)

    # deskew (unrotate) the rotated rectangle
    deskewed = cv2.warpAffine(blob_img, M, (ww, hh), flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)

    # threshold it again
    deskewed = cv2.threshold(deskewed, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

    # get bounding box of contour of deskewed rectangle
    cntrs = cv2.findContours(deskewed, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cntrs = cntrs[0] if len(cntrs) == 2 else cntrs[1]
    cntr = cntrs[0]
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cntr)

    # crop to white region
    crop = deskewed[y:y+h, x:x+w]

    # alternately crop the input
    #crop = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]

    # save deskewed image
    cv2.imwrite("bw2_deskewed_{0}.png".format(i),crop)
    print("")
    i = i + 1

# save contour and rot rect images
cv2.imwrite("bw2_contours.png",contour_img)
cv2.imwrite("bw2_rotrects.png",rotrect_img)

# display result, though it won't show transparency
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("clean", clean)
cv2.imshow("contours", contour_img)
cv2.imshow("rectangles", rotrect_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Contour image:

[image]

Rotated rectangles images:

[image]

First 3 unrotated images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Affine warp rotation angles:

```
13.916877746582031
-42.87890625
18.8118896484375
-44.333797454833984
-38.65980911254883
-37.25965881347656
8.806793212890625
14.931419372558594
-37.405357360839844
-34.99202346801758
35.537681579589844
-35.350345611572266
-42.3245735168457
50.12316131591797
-42.969085693359375
52.750038146972656
45.0
```

Answer (score 2):

your code is correct for detecting those patches, only a minor mistake is here

```
if cv2.contourArea(c) < 3000:
    continue
```

reduce 3000 to 100 or below values, because your are giving a condition as contours below 3000 to be neglect